# insmod on VirtualBox - error inserting a jprobe module.

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtualbox, kernel-module

I am trying to create a kernel module that plants a jprobe in (on?) the getdents system call. All I have so far is the basic skeleton taken from this website: http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~boutcher/kprobes/. My problem is that I cannot insert the module once it compiles. The output I get is:

```
sudo insmod ./final.ko
insmod: error inserting './final.ko': -1 Operation not permitted
```

I have tried making the most basic module possible, and this module is inserted correctly. I have no idea what could be wrong, and I do not know how to get any more debug information. I am running Ubuntu 11.10 in VirtualBox on an OS X host. I am running kernel version 3.0.0-12.

Comment: The most likely reason for getting `EPERM` on module insertion is a lack of capabilities.  I can see you're using `sudo`, but how is it configured?  Maybe try bypassing `sudo` and becoming the superuser directly?  If you run `sudo -i` and then `su -`, that should work.

Comment: You have probably looked at the messages in the system log already? If not, try `dmesg | less`. Are there any details there?

Comment: As far as I can see, the init function of that example uses return code (-1) to report an error. -1 is -EPERM, which exactly corresponds to "Operation not permitted" error. Ideally, the authors of that example should have used a more meaningful return code in init. Anyway, the system log probably contains the details.

Comment: In addition, that example seems outdated. Take a look at the [kprobe/jprobe examples](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/samples/kprobes/) in the Linux kernel sources. The jprobe example looks different now, at least at the first glance.